# Early boarding and late disembarking for the night-time Heysham – Isle of Man ferry (foot passenger)

Tags: uk, ferries, isle-of-man

The night-time ferry from Heysham to the Isle of Man departs 02:15 and arrives 06:00.  As a foot passenger, what is the earliest I can enter the ferry?  And when do I need to vacate the cabin by the latest?  Check-in appears to open at 22:30 but I wouldn't like to have to sit in the ferry terminal until 01:30 before I can enter my cabin (in that case I might opt for the daytime ferry).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have e-mailed IOM.Reservations@Steam-Packet.com and received the following reply:

> The terminal itself will open from 22:30hrs, and the vessel will normally start reloading around 01:00 - 01:15hrs.
>
> You will need to vacate the cabin once the vessel arrives in Douglas which will be approximately 05:45 - 06:00hrs.